# Linq Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I m new to Linq syntax and getting an error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.MethodInfo`>' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.MethodBase`>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

on the following line in my application

```
 IEnumerable<MethodBase> methods = 
                    from p in defaultMembers.OfType<PropertyInfo>()
                    select p.GetGetMethod() into m
                    where m != null
                    select m;
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Your code works just fine. Are you sure that's the line which cause the problem?

Comment: I m working on a some else code and when I build it in .net framework 4.0 it builds fine but does not build in 3.5 and i get the above error

Comment: OK, I see where is the problem. `IEnumerable<T>` is not covariant in .NET 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is not covariant in .NET 3.5 (it is in .NET4+). That's why you can't assign `IEnumerable<ChildClass>` to `IEnumerable<ParentClass>`.

Change your variable declaration to exactly match the query results (using `var` and implicitly typed variable or specifying the correct type):

```
 IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methods = 
                    from p in defaultMembers.OfType<PropertyInfo>()
                    select p.GetGetMethod() into m
                    where m != null
                    select m;
```

Or if you really need `IEnumerable<MethodBase>` add additional cast into your query:

```
 IEnumerable<MethodBase> methods = 
                    from p in defaultMembers.OfType<PropertyInfo>()
                    select p.GetGetMethod() into m
                    where m != null
                    select (MethodBase)m;
```